# Circular (round) UIView resizing with AutoLayout... how to animate cornerRadius during the resize animation?

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a subclassed UIView that we can call `CircleView`. CircleView automatically sets a corner radius to half of its width in order for it to be a circle.

The problem is that when "CircleView" is resized by an AutoLayout constraint... for example **on a device rotation**... it distorts badly until the resize takes place because the "cornerRadius" property has to catch up, and the OS only sends a single "bounds" change to the view's frame.

I was wondering if anyone had a good, clear strategy for implementing "CircleView" in a way that won't distort in such instances, **but will still mask its contents to the shape of a circle and allow for a border to exist around said UIView.**

Comment: Where do you put the code to automatically reset the `corner radius`?

Comment: @J.Wang Have tried multiple places. The problem is that I've found that I'm only receiving a notification of a bounds change for the circle a single time, and animating the cornerRadius alongside the OS's changing of the constraints seems to be really inconsistent.

Comment: How about `layoutSubviews()` method?

Comment: @J.Wang That only gets called once on resize/rotate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a smoothly resizable circular UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669051/how-do-i-create-a-smoothly-resizable-circular-uiview)

Comment: @Simon It's not a duplicate, the answer is not in the other question, but it's in this one.

Comment: @BenGuild the same answer is in both, but in that one it's in ObjC and in this one it's in swift.  But it's not the answer which is flagged as a duplicate, it's the question, and the questions are the same.

Comment: @Simon, the answers are different but similar. He mentions it's inspired by yours. Also, he did a nice job of explaining it and visualizing it. I tried `SGBRoundView` and it didn't work as well as his answer.

Comment: Just check atleast once its working in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362934/how-to-keep-a-round-imageview-round-using-auto-layout/43998774#43998774

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### UPDATE: If your deployment target is iOS 11 or later:

Starting in iOS 11, UIKit will animate `cornerRadius` if you update it inside an animation block. Just set your view's `layer.cornerRadius` in a `UIView` animation block, or (to handle interface orientation changes), set it in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

### ORIGINAL: If your deployment target is older than iOS 11:

So you want this:

[image: smoothly resizing circle view]

(I turned on Debug > Slow Animations to make the smoothness easier to see.)

**Side rant,** feel free to skip this paragraph: This turns out to be a lot harder than it should be, because the iOS SDK doesn't make the parameters (duration, timing curve) of the autorotation animation available in a convenient way. You can (I think) get at them by overriding `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` on your view controller to call `-animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` on the transition coordinator, and in the callback you pass, get the `transitionDuration` and `completionCurve` from the `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext`. And then you need to pass that information down to your `CircleView`, which has to save it (because it hasn't been resized yet!) and later when it receives `layoutSubviews`, it can use it to create a `CABasicAnimation` for `cornerRadius` with those saved animation parameters. And don't accidentally create an animation when it's **not** an animated resize… **End of side rant.**

Wow, that sounds like a ton of work, and you have to involve the view controller. Here's another approach that's entirely implemented inside `CircleView`. It works now (in iOS 9) but I can't guarantee it'll always work in the future, because it makes two assumptions that could theoretically be wrong in the future.

Here's the approach: override `-actionForLayer:forKey:` in `CircleView` to return an action that, when run, installs an animation for `cornerRadius`.

These are the two assumptions:

- `bounds.origin` and `bounds.size` get separate animations. (This is true now but presumably a future iOS could use a single animation for `bounds`. It would be easy enough to check for a `bounds` animation if no `bounds.size` animation were found.)
- The `bounds.size` animation is added to the layer before Core Animation asks for the `cornerRadius` action.

Given these assumptions, when Core Animation asks for the `cornerRadius` action, we can get the `bounds.size` animation from the layer, copy it, and modify the copy to animate `cornerRadius` instead. The copy has the same animation parameters as the original (unless we modify them), so it has the correct duration and timing curve.

Here's the start of `CircleView`:

```
class CircleView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    private func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
    }
```

Note that the view's bounds are set before the view receives `layoutSubviews`, and therefore before we update `cornerRadius`. This is why the `bounds.size` animation is installed before the `cornerRadius` animation is requested. Each property's animations are installed inside the property's setter.

When we set `cornerRadius`, Core Animation asks us for a `CAAction` to run for it:

```
    override func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == "cornerRadius" {
            if let boundsAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation {
                let animation = boundsAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
                animation.keyPath = "cornerRadius"
                let action = Action()
                action.pendingAnimation = animation
                action.priorCornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
                return action
            }
        }
        return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
    }
```

In the code above, if we're asked for an action for `cornerRadius`, we look for a `CABasicAnimation` on `bounds.size`. If we find one, we copy it, change the key path to `cornerRadius`, and save it away in a custom `CAAction` (of class `Action`, which I will show below). We also save the current value of the `cornerRadius` property, because Core Animation calls `actionForLayer:forKey:` **before** updating the property.

After `actionForLayer:forKey:` returns, Core Animation updates the `cornerRadius` property of the layer. Then it runs the action by sending it `runActionForKey:object:arguments:`. The job of the action is to install whatever animations are appropriate. Here's the custom subclass of `CAAction`, which I've nested inside `CircleView`:

```
    private class Action: NSObject, CAAction {
        var pendingAnimation: CABasicAnimation?
        var priorCornerRadius: CGFloat = 0
        public func run(forKey event: String, object anObject: Any, arguments dict: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
            if let layer = anObject as? CALayer, let pendingAnimation = pendingAnimation {
                if pendingAnimation.isAdditive {
                    pendingAnimation.fromValue = priorCornerRadius - layer.cornerRadius
                    pendingAnimation.toValue = 0
                } else {
                    pendingAnimation.fromValue = priorCornerRadius
                    pendingAnimation.toValue = layer.cornerRadius
                }
                layer.add(pendingAnimation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
            }
        }
    }
} // end of CircleView
```

The `runActionForKey:object:arguments:` method sets the `fromValue` and `toValue` properties of the animation and then adds the animation to the layer. There's a complication: UIKit uses “additive” animations, because they work better if you start another animation on a property while an earlier animation is still running. So our action checks for that.

If the animation is additive, it sets `fromValue` to the difference between the old and new corner radii, and sets `toValue` to zero. Since the layer's `cornerRadius` property has already been updated by the time the animation is running, adding that `fromValue` at the start of the animation makes it look like the old corner radius, and adding the `toValue` of zero at the end of the animation makes it look like the new corner radius.

If the animation is not additive (which doesn't happen if UIKit created the animation, as far as I know), then it just sets the `fromValue` and `toValue` in the obvious way.

Here's the whole file for your convenience:

```
import UIKit

class CircleView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateCornerRadius()
    }

    private func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
    }

    override func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
        if event == "cornerRadius" {
            if let boundsAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation {
                let animation = boundsAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
                animation.keyPath = "cornerRadius"
                let action = Action()
                action.pendingAnimation = animation
                action.priorCornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
                return action
            }
        }
        return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
    }

    private class Action: NSObject, CAAction {
        var pendingAnimation: CABasicAnimation?
        var priorCornerRadius: CGFloat = 0
        public func run(forKey event: String, object anObject: Any, arguments dict: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
            if let layer = anObject as? CALayer, let pendingAnimation = pendingAnimation {
                if pendingAnimation.isAdditive {
                    pendingAnimation.fromValue = priorCornerRadius - layer.cornerRadius
                    pendingAnimation.toValue = 0
                } else {
                    pendingAnimation.fromValue = priorCornerRadius
                    pendingAnimation.toValue = layer.cornerRadius
                }
                layer.add(pendingAnimation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
            }
        }
    }
} // end of CircleView
```

My answer was inspired by [this answer by Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902063/77567).

Comment: Thanks! You should release this as a Cocoa Pod. :)

Comment: Thanks to @sethmr for converting this to Swift 3.

Comment: @robmayoff I couldn't get it to work for my purposes though. If you take a look at [SwiftySwitch](https://github.com/Sethmr/SwiftySwitch) I am trying to get the circle to animate perfectly circular. It doesn't look bad as is, but I wouldn't mind getting it to work for future reference. I tried making the tempView I use for the expanding/detracting circle that class and was unsure of how to approach it next.

Comment: I took a quick look at your project but I don't see any use of `CircleView` or the techniques described in this answer. I tested your version of my code in a playground and it worked. Anyway, you should post your own question if you are having trouble.

Comment: @robmayoff You got it ;)

Comment: @robmayoff Awesome answer! This worked perfectly for me. What would you do if you wanted to handle a gradient layer in the same manner. As in, I want a layer to update its bounds without a delay.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks for the answer, very helpful.  Unfortunately, I found that it didn't work on iPad (under iOS 9 and 10).  By combining your answer with the original one by Simon, I was able to get something working for both iPad and iPhone:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42535317/90918

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds upon [the earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714554/90918) by [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff).  Basically, I implemented it for our project and it worked just fine on the iPhone (iOS 9 and 10), but the issue remained on iPad (iOS 9 or 10).

Debugging, I found that the if statement:

```
if let boundsAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation {
```

always failed on iPad.  It looks like the animations are built in a different sequence on iPad than iPhone.  Looking back at the [original answer by Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902063/77567), it seems that sequencing has changed before.  So I combined both answers giving me something like this:

```
override func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
    let buildAction: (CABasicAnimation) -> Action = { boundsAnimation in
        let animation = boundsAnimation.copy() as! CABasicAnimation
        animation.keyPath = "cornerRadius"
        let action = Action()
        action.pendingAnimation = animation
        action.priorCornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius
        return action
    }

    if event == "cornerRadius" {
        if let boundsAnimation = layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation {
            return buildAction(boundsAnimation)
        } else if let boundsAnimation = self.action(for: layer, forKey: "bounds") as? CABasicAnimation {
            return buildAction(boundsAnimation)
        }
    }

    return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
}
```

By combining both answers, it seems to work properly on both iPhone and iPad under iOS 9 and 10.  I haven't really tested further, and don't know enough about CoreAnimation to fully understand this change.

Comment: Sadly this now seems to be broken on the new iOS version 10.3, the animation is once again squared.  Anyone have any idea's for this.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10 you don't need to create a CAAction, it works just creating a CABasicAnimation and provide this in your action(for layer:, for key:) -> CAAction? function (See Swift example):

```
private var currentBoundsAnimation: CABasicAnimation? {
    return layer.animation(forKey: "bounds.size") as? CABasicAnimation ?? layer.animation(forKey: "bounds") as? CABasicAnimation
}

override public var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
    }
}

override public func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction? {
    if(event == "cornerRadius"), let boundsAnimation = currentBoundsAnimation {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
        animation.duration = boundsAnimation.duration
        animation.timingFunction = boundsAnimation.timingFunction
        return animation
    }

    return super.action(for: layer, forKey: event)
}
```

Instead of overriding the bounds property you can also override the layoutSubviews:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
}
```

This works magically because the CABasicAnimation infers the missing from and to values from the model and presentation layers. To set the timing correctly you need the private currentBoundsAnimation property to get the current animations ("bounds" for iPad and "bounds.size" for iPhone) which where added on device rotation.

Answer (score 0):

These translation answers usually go Objective-c ==> Swift, but in case there are any more stubborn Objective-c authors left, here's @Rob's answer translated...

```
// see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714554/294949

#import "RoundView.h"

@interface Action : NSObject<CAAction>
@property(strong,nonatomic) CABasicAnimation *pendingAnimation;
@property(assign,nonatomic) CGFloat priorCornerRadius;
@end

@implementation Action
- (void)runActionForKey:(NSString *)event object:(id)anObject
              arguments:(nullable NSDictionary *)dict {

    if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[CALayer self]]) {
        CALayer *layer = (CALayer *)anObject;
        if (self.pendingAnimation.isAdditive) {
            self.pendingAnimation.fromValue = @(self.priorCornerRadius - layer.cornerRadius);
            self.pendingAnimation.toValue = @(0);
        } else {
            self.pendingAnimation.fromValue = @(self.priorCornerRadius);
            self.pendingAnimation.toValue = @(layer.cornerRadius);
        }
        [layer addAnimation:self.pendingAnimation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
    }
}
@end

@interface RoundView ()
@property(weak,nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@end

@implementation RoundView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self updateCornerRadius];
}

- (void)updateCornerRadius {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = MIN(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)/2.0;
}

- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event {
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"cornerRadius"]) {
        CABasicAnimation *boundsAnimation = (CABasicAnimation *)[self.layer animationForKey:@"bounds.size"];
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [boundsAnimation copy];
        animation.keyPath = @"cornerRadius";
        Action *action = [[Action alloc] init];
        action.pendingAnimation = animation;
        action.priorCornerRadius = layer.cornerRadius;
        return action;
    }
    return [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event];;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest not using a corner radius, but instead using a CAShapeLayer as a mask for your view's content layer.

You'd install a filled 360° arc CGPath as the shape of the shape layer and set it as the mask of your layer's view.

You could then either animate a new scale transform for the mask layer, or animate a change to the radius of the path. Both methods should stay round, although the scale transform might not give you a clean shape at smaller pixel sizes.

The timing would be the tricky part (getting the animation of the mask layer to happen in lockstep with the bounds animation.)

Comment: Right, so this doesn't really solve the issue then. I agree using a CAShapeLayer as the mask is a better approach, but hard-coding to match the resize/rotate animation's delay doesn't really seem like a good strategy.